# Altair hangs with this chart?

Tags: altair

I have a simple csv with the following contents:

```
Pattern, Mode, Bandwidth
Random, Read, 23.988
Random, Write, 30.628
Seq, Read, 38.000
Seq, Write, 33.785
```

I want to produce a similar grouped bar chart as [this one](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart_horizontal.html):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("simple.csv")
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Bandwidth:Q',
    y='Mode:N',
    row='Pattern:N'
)
```

Just hangs altair (I have to kill the session of jupyter notebook to get out of it).
That said, if I manually put in the data: `pd.DataFrame([ ], [], columns = []`. The same drawing command seems work, partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have spaces in your CSV file, so the column names are not `'Mode'` and `'Bandwidth'`, but rather `' Mode'` and `' Bandwidth'` (with leading spaces).

The best fix would be to remove spaces from your CSV file. If that is not possible, then in pandas, you can pass the `skipinitialspace=True` argument to `pd.read_csv` to strip these spaces when reading the data into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, it appears I didn't pass in `skipinitialspace=True` when I read CSV file, and it messed up the column names.